# Collect fails to collect all powers of my variable

Tags: replacement, formatting

I am fairly new to mathematica and have not used it to really code anything at all, but just used it as an kind of advanced calculator.

My issue is the following: I need to extract the power of a variable in a function i defined for the final steps of some physics calculations (meaning i actually plug in numbers).

Therefore, i defined the function, defined all the variables within the function, plugged in the number i need and used Collect[exp,k, Expand].
Then i hoped to find some results like 'whatever*k^(the number)'. 
Instead, it does not really collect all the powers, but just a few of them.

At first (after looking at other Collect threads on here) i thought it was due to using fractions at one place and rational numbers at another, but no matter what i replaced (like using 2.0 instead of 2), mathematica refused to expand a simple product and collect everything in terms of my variable.
Its not like i dont know my result, but it bothers me that i dont know what is going on and that i am unable to fix it.

So, heres the code:

```
Cs[x_] = A^2*(1 - (1 - 2*x)/(2*x))^(-2)*(9/4 *(-n)^(2.0*x - 2.0) + 
B^2/(4*x^2)*(-n)^(6.0*x))
A = Sqrt[h/2]*k^(-1.5)/σ^1
B = σ^2.0*k^3.0
n = -2^(1/6.)*σ^(-1.5)*k^-1
```

giving...

```
Collect[Cs[1/(1 - 0.3/2.0)], k, Expand]
(0.472388 h (1/(k σ^1.5))^0.352941)/(k^3. σ^2) +0.0822886 h k^3. (1/(k σ^1.5))^7.05882 σ^2.
```

Here, it does not collect the (k*sigma)^(some number) with the k^-3 * sigma^-2 and i dont see why.

Thanks for the help!
Best,
Nico

Comment: Well, it **is** collecting powers of **k**. Just it doesn't show them as you want

Comment: Okay, i guess Collect was not the thing i was looking for. Instead, i solved the problem by simplifying my result with the additional assumption that k is positive. Thanks!